# Access SQL: Calculating Min date value and duration for each day

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking at GPS data for vehicles, composed of the following information:

```
vehicle        day              ignition   landmark
---------------------------------------------------
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 14:32   on         
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 15:10   off        Random Place B
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 15:15   on         Random Place B
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 15:20   off
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:14  on
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:20  off        Random Place H
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:22  on         Random Place H
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:24  off
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 12:10   on         Random Place ZZ
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 12:12   on         
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 12:15   off        Random Place ZY
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 13:10   on         Random Place ZY
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 13:15   off
```

I'm trying to find the **first** ignition *off* point where landmark is Not Null, and the **last** ignition *on* point where landmark is Not Null for **each day**. Ideally, a calculated field for "duration" could be included to display the DateDiff between those two values.

**Target Output:**

```
    vehicle        day          ignition   landmark  
---------------------------------------------------------
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 15:10   off        Random Place B
Sample Guy 1   7/5/2013 15:15   on         Random Place B
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:20  off        Random Place H
Sample Guy 1   7/20/2013 18:22  on         Random Place H
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 12:15   off        Random Place ZY
Sample Guy 2   8/1/2013 13:10   on         Random Place ZY
```

I understand this may be complex, but I'm looking to start understanding the building blocks to completing this.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=111383 i dunno if this is what your looking for but it looks like they got it in one query

Comment: @Mr.Monshaw That is a SQL server implementation. Access does not support the row_number partitioning function. OP, I would suggest to start with googling an "Access row_number " or "Access windowing / partitioning function" implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you must have in your GPS data table is a unique primary key. I don't think you can solve this problem without one.

If you don't already have one, just add an `AutoNumber` field called `ID` to your `GPSData` table

Here is a query that will work in Access once you have done that:

```
SELECT R.ResultID,
       vehicle,
       day,
       ignition,
       landmark
FROM   (SELECT First(ID) AS ResultID
        FROM   (SELECT ID,
                       vehicle,
                       DateSerial(day([day]), month([day]), year([day])) AS NormalisedDate,
                       ignition
                FROM   GPSData
                WHERE  ((ignition = "off") AND (landmark IS NOT NULL))
                ORDER  BY day ASC)
        GROUP  BY vehicle, normalisedDate, ignition
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Last(ID) AS ResultID
        FROM   (SELECT ID,
                       vehicle,
                       DateSerial(day([day]), month([day]), year([day])) AS NormalisedDate,
                       ignition
                FROM   GPSData
                WHERE  ((ignition = "on") AND (landmark IS NOT NULL))
                ORDER  BY day ASC)
        GROUP  BY vehicle, NormalisedDate, ignition) AS R
       INNER JOIN GPSData
         ON R.ResultID = GPSData.ID
ORDER  BY vehicle, day
```

There may be a better way of doing this, but this should work, even though it's not trying to be clever.

Basically, we split the problem into smaller chunks that we then re-construct:

- Find the ID of all daily records for all vehicles that are first 'off'.
  To find this list, we must group the data by day, so we must normalise the datetime `day` to its date part only.
- do the exact same thing, but for the last 'on' record of each day.
- `UNION ALL` these 2 lists to get us the ID (let's call it `ResultID`) of all records that match both the first daily 'off' and last daily 'on' of each vehicle.
- re-JOIN this list of record IDs with the original `GPSData`.